# Check Network for two different type of devices

Tags: android, connection

I'm facing an issue with my method to check if a device is connected to the Wifi or Phone Data.
In fact, it works very well on phones but on tablet...it crashes.
The reason for it is that some tablet dont have ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE.

So how could I write my method in the way that if the Device has TYPE_MOBILE capabilities, it checks for it, otherwise simply the TYPE_WIFI?

Here is my actual method:

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {

    boolean isConnected = false;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfoWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    NetworkInfo networkInfoMobile = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (networkInfoWifi.isConnected()|| networkInfoMobile.isConnected()) {
        isConnected = true;
    }

    return isConnected;
}
```

Thx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for null before using isConnected() :

```
if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) != null)
{
    //implement your business
}
```

or before getting your Network info detect that your device is Tablet or not :

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context)
{
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

then get your network info according to the device

Answer (score 0):

```
   TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
int type=getPhoneType(telephonyManager); 
if(type !=0) 
{ 
NetworkInfo networkInfoWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
NetworkInfo networkInfoMobile = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
if (networkInfoWifi.isConnected()|| networkInfoMobile.isConnected()) 
{ isConnected = true; }
} 
else
{
NetworkInfo networkInfoWifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
if (networkInfoWifi.isConnected()) { isConnected = true; } }
```

The value of "type" tells us if the radio is GSM or CDMA or IF the radio is not present. It is 0 if no radio is present, 1 if it is GSM and 2 if it is CDMA